# counting carry operations in C

Tags: c, module

I'm trying to work on a program written in C that calculates the addition of 2 binary numbers and prints out the work with the carry line above, as shown here

[image]

I need help specifically with the "carry" row calculation which I can't seem to get to work.

My idea was to check if the sum of the end digit of each number and carry row results in 0,1,2 or 3, and depending on the sum.

If the sum is 2 or 3, there will be a "carry" 1 and so the program adds 1 and multiplies by 10.

If the sum is 0 or 1, there will be no "carry" and so the program multiplies by 10.

I don't know where the flaw in the logic is and I'd really appreciate some help.

```
carry = 0;
count =0;

while ((num1Temp > 0) || (num2Temp > 0))
{
    count++;
    if (((num1Temp % ten) + (num2Temp % ten) + (carry % ten)) == 3)
    {
        carry++;
        carry = carry + pow(ten, count);
    }
    else if (((num1Temp % ten) + (num2Temp % ten) + (carry % ten)) == 2)
    {
        carry = carry + pow(ten, count);
        carry++;
    }
    else if (((num1Temp % ten) + (num2Temp % ten) + (carry % ten)) == 1)
    {
        carry = carry * ten;
    }
    else if (((num1Temp % ten) + (num2Temp % ten) + (carry % ten)) == 0)
    {
        carry = carry * ten;
    }
    num1Temp = num1Temp / ten;
    num2Temp = num2Temp / ten;
}
```

Comment: Note: try to avoid `pow()` with integer calculations. Instead of incrementing the `count++` power in each loop, multiply a value by `10`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Look at the way you use `carry`. You seem unclear on whether to use the first digit or the last. Once you are clear on that you can look at something like `carry % ten` and decide whether it actually does what you want.

Answer (score -1):

**1**.Main flaw I think
In your program, there is no way you are getting to the leftmost bit **1**01 of the **num1Temp** (**5**) or **num2Temp** (**5**) to calculate carry
to achieve that (**1**01) I have written instructions like

```
if (num1Temp == 1)
        {
            if (((11 % ten) + (num2Temp % ten) + (carry/ indice(10,count))) > 1)
            {
                carry = carry + indice(ten, count+1);
            }
        }
```

**2**.and also I don't think we have to do anything with value of **carry** when sum is less than **2**
that's why I've skipped

```
else if (((num1Temp % ten) + (num2Temp % ten) + (carry % ten)) == 1)
    {
        carry = carry * ten;
    }
    else if (((num1Temp % ten) + (num2Temp % ten) + (carry % ten)) == 0)
    {
        carry = carry * ten;
    }
```

**3**.To get the carry bit simply, I've changed

```
(carry % ten)
```

with

```
(carry/ indice(10,count)
```

modified version of you code

```
int main()
{
    int num1Temp=binary_8t(5);
    int num2Temp=binary_8t(5);
    int carry =0;
    int count =0;
    int ten=10;

while ((num1Temp > 0) || (num2Temp > 0))
{
    if (num1Temp && num2Temp)
    {
      if (num1Temp == 1)
        {
        if (((11 % ten) + (11 % ten) + (carry/ indice(10,count))) > 1)
            {
                carry = carry + indice(ten, count+1);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(1)
    {
        if (num1Temp == 1)
        {
            if (((11 % ten) + (num2Temp % ten) + (carry/ indice(10,count))) > 1)
            {
                carry = carry + indice(ten, count+1);
            }
        }
    
        if (num2Temp == 1)
        {
            if (((11 % ten) + (num2Temp % ten) + (carry/ indice(10,count))) > 1)
            {
                carry = carry + indice(ten, count+1);
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (((num1Temp % ten) + (num2Temp % ten) + (carry/ indice(10,count))) == 3)
    {

        carry = carry + indice(ten, count+1);

    }
    else if (((num1Temp % ten) + (num2Temp % ten) + (carry/ indice(10,count))) == 2)
    {

        carry = carry + indice(ten, count+1);
    }

    num1Temp = num1Temp / ten;
    num2Temp = num2Temp / ten;
    count++;
}
    printf("\nFinal carry: %d",carry);
    return 0;
}
```

and **power()** and **binary_8t** are my own functions, those used.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the details of the fixes you have done.